# Does clone method on array a deep or a shallow copy?

Tags: java

I'm not sure if the following will result in deep or shallow copy?

```
public void viewImages(final String[] instancesFilename) {

    String[] instances = (String[])instancesFilename.clone();    
}
```

Is there a simple and fast way to deep copy a string array?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Strings in Java are imutable(Can't change their value). So there is no detectable difference between a deep and shallow copy when copying strings.

And just to further reference: The copy will be shallow but that should not be a problem since strings are imutable.

Oh and funny fact: Strings can't be cloned with the clone method, so if you try to do a deep copy of strings with the clone method, you will get a CloneNotSupportedException.

Comment: The author is asking to copy `String[]`, not `String`. The elements of `instancesFilename` could be changed later from the outside, so the OP wants to create a copy of the array.

Comment: Well it's *detectable* (are the references the same) but if you're using the strings properly, it shouldn't be *significant*.

Comment: @PhilippReichart: But the OP is already performing a clone - "deep copy" vs "shallow copy" in that context can only be about whether the strings are cloned or not - and as this answer states, it's almost always unimportant.

Comment: ... But the String can be `intern()`'d, which would make kind of a shallow copy :\

Comment: Just want to make sure I do not reference in any way the array I got as parameter. I can create a new array and for loop copy. But I think this will result in slower and same behavior

Comment: Your clone method will create a new independent array with new references to the same string objects. Which most likely is what you want/need. But your new references will point to the same String objects as the original Array. But I can't imagine why this would be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The array class also has the copyOf method.  This is generally what I use for creating copies of arrays.  Heres and explanation of all of the differences: http://forum.codecall.net/topic/49450-copying-arrays/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting [article discussing using serialization to make deep copies](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip76.html).

The objects in the call graph do need to support serialization however in many business types of 3 Tier applications, that necessity is there.

The article provides a discussion of deep copy and shallow copy with some diagrams.